# Theme mode get reset when reopen the app. How can I make it not get reset everytime

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have implements the theme mode into the app. But the problem is when I quit the app and open it again the theme mode(dark mode) get reset all the time. How can I solve that problem.

Some of the code: Theme Screen

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    themeManager.removeListener(themeListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    themeManager.addListener(themeListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  themeListener() {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
 
   //Button
     Switch(
            activeColor: Colors.grey,
            value: themeManager.themeMode == ThemeMode.dark,
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              themeManager.toggleTheme(newValue);
            }),
```

I haven’t done anything yet in the LoginScreen

I have set `home: const LoginScreen(),` in main.dart
when I open the app I want it to check that if the app has changed the theme or not.If yes then set to dark mode automatically. How can I achieve such as that.
***If you guys know how to do it please help. Or provide some link.*** *

Comment: Consider saving on local db like [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Answer (score 1):

I did that by saving using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). Then, it's simple to just pull the value. Since my app just has two themes, I saved it as a boolean.

Be aware that they do say "there is no guarantee that writes will be persisted to disk after returning, so this plugin must not be used for storing critical data." Since I don't consider theme a critical piece of data, I've been using it. I've had issues with larger amounts of data being lost, but not the theme so far.